# LINQ LEFT JOIN With a LIST<String>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

Say you have a list of IDs:

```
string str = "82174F2000000, 82174F2000001, 82174F2000002, 82174F2000003, 82174F2000004, 82174F2000005";
```

And you do this:

```
var tids = new List<string>(str.Replace(", ", ",").Split(','));
var tntable = tids.AsQueryable();
```

And you want to compare it to a table with a Left Join:

```
var line = from c in db.Ctable
 join l  in tntable on c.CarID equals l.CarID into c_j
  from l in c_j.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new
  {
 Name =  c.OwnerName,
 Hours = c.Hours
  };
```

looks like the tntable doesn't have a field called 'CarID'.

Can someone please help?

This is for LINQ to Entity.

I have seen this:

[How to compare List<String> to DB Table using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922619/how-to-compare-liststring-to-db-table-using-linq)

But don't know to do a LEFT JOIN.

TIA!

I know this is long; but thanks for reading.

**UPDATED FOR MichaC:**

In the database in CTable we have these CarIDs:

```
CarID
_____
82174F2000000
82174F2000001
82174F2000002
82174F2000003
```

Let's just say the table (tntable) contains the string broken down into records:

```
CarID
_____
82174F2000000
82174F2000001
82174F2000002
82174F2000003
82174F2000004
82174F2000005
```

So, a LEFT JOIN like this:

```
SELECT C.CarID, T.CarID
FROM CTable C
LEFT JOIN tntable T ON C.CarID = T.CarID
```

Will yield you this:

```
T.CarID         C.CarID
_______         _______
82174F2000000   82174F2000000
82174F2000001   82174F2000001
82174F2000002   82174F2000002
82174F2000003   82174F2000003
82174F2000004   NULL
82174F2000005   NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right it looks like you want to filter based on a list of IDs, not perform a left join. I think you want something like this:

```
var line = from c in db.Ctable
           where tntable.Contains(c.CarID)
           select new 
           {
              Name =  c.OwnerName,
              Hours = c.Hours
           };
```

UPDATE: You can move the Contains check to the select statement to return everything.

```
var line = from c in db.Ctable
           select new 
           {
              IsMatch = tntable.Contains(c.CarID),
              Name =  c.OwnerName,
              Hours = c.Hours
           };
```

UPDATE 2: Ok how about this. Use my original to pull the relevant items from SQL, then use Linq to Objects to actually build the list the way you want. The .ToList() forces it to make the SQL query. You could also use .AsEnumerable().

```
var filtered = from c in db.Ctable
           where tntable.Contains(c.CarID)
           select new 
           {
              CarID = c.CarID,
              Name =  c.OwnerName,
              Hours = c.Hours
           };

var line = from x in tntable
           join i in filtered.ToList() on x equals u.CarID into i_match
           from i in i_match.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select { x, i };
```

Comment: not only do I want to know what's in CTable, but I want to return NULL as well (not in CTable). The example you have returns only what's in CTable. thanks!

Comment: that's very cool if it works. I will try it now and report back.

Comment: MichaC, that's one way to get it to work, but it's not really a LEFT JOIN. You see CTable has millions of records and the above will return those millions. Any ideas how to do a LEFT JOIN so that it will only return at the most what's in the string?

Comment: I think the problem is I don't quite understand what you're looking for. Option A will return just the matches instead of the millions of rows, but your first comment suggested to me you wanted everything returned with an indication of whether each row is in your list, hence Option B. If you don't want the OwnerName and Hours for all the millions of non-matches (items not in tntable) doesn't Option A give you everything you need? Do you need a count of non-matches?

Comment: Thanks MichaC, I've edited the question with a detail of what I'm trying to achive, please see 'UPDATED FOR MichaC:'. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From you comment you want null to still select an object for every ID in `tntable` even if the id is not found in `ctable`?  If I understand that correctly then, I believe this give you the desired effect.

```
var desired = from l in tntable
              join c in ctable on l equals c.CarID into lj
              from c in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select
                  new
                      {
                          Name = c == null ? null : c.OwnerName,
                          Hours = c == null ? (int?)null : c.Hours
                      };
```

Comment: the error is this 'l.CarID' b/c tntable doesn't have a field called 'CarID'. So I was thinking do I have to create a Model (class) with a field called 'CarID' and then do a List<SomCarTable> table2 = new List<SomCarTable>(); and then add each value from the string into the it. Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh I was testing this with LINQ to Objects and it worked fine there, I cannot reproduce your particular error when I created a DB model the error I get if far more cryptic (This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.).  I obviously do not know enough about Entity Framework to provide your answer.  Sorry.

Comment: thanks vossad01 for even trying; but you know i like your NULL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this :

```
string str = "Pat, Boots";
var names = new List<string>(str.Replace(", ", ",").Split(',')).AsQueryable();

Pet defaultPet = new Pet { Name = "Default Pet", Age = -1 };

List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet>{ 
            new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8 },
            new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4 },
            new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1 } 
    };

var pets = from name in names
            join pet in pets1 on name equals pet.Name into gj
            from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPet)
            select new { Name = name, Age = subpet.Age };


foreach(var newPet in pets) {
    Console.WriteLine("\nName: {0}, Age: {1} ", newPet.Name, newPet.Age );
}
```

This produces:

```
Name: Pat, Age: -1
Name: Boots, Age: 4
```

If this doesn't do what you want then have a closer look at [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx).

I used the above link and MSDN's help page for DefaultIfEmpty().

Comment: Thanks Tymek. I'm not on a puter where I can run your example; but it looks like it will work for Link to Object. Have you tried to query a table in a db and left join to a string (non-db)? I'm pretty sure this is a very common task. User types in a bunch of text and you figure out if they're in the table or not. Thanks!

Comment: if you go MSDN forum and do a search on linq+to+entity+left+join+string or linq+to+entity+string you'll get 1 post.